# High pitched sound coming from car when heat is on

Tags: toyota, camry, hybrid

Dont know whats happening with my car. Every time I turn the heat on I hear slight rattling sound coming from my car. When AC is on then its less noticeable but with heat its quite loud. Btw its a Toyota Camry hybrid. Any clues?